# Create a List with the common elements and count of repetition

Tags: c#, linq, datagridview

I have 4 var from 4 different datagridview and I get the a selection of value with a Linq query like this:

```
var Sums = dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>()
          .Where(row => row.Cells[7].Value != null)
        .GroupBy(row => row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) //inserire colonna gruppo

        .Select(g => new { Gruppo = g.Key, Serie = g.Sum(row => Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Value)) });
```

So each var looks similar to this:

```
Gruppo | Serie

group1 |  3
group2 |  2
group3 |  7
```

What I'm trying to do is to obtain a list with the intersection of multiple list and the count of repetition of every " Gruppo" element.

The results must be something like this:

```
Gruppo | Repetition

group1 |  2 (if is present in two lists)
group2 |  3 (if is present in three lists)
group3 |  1 (if is present in one lists)
```

Now I have the common element with this code:

```
var pp = Sums.Intersect(Sums2);
```

but find only the elements with the same "Gruppo" and same "Serie" so if "gruppo" it's equal but serie is not, the intersect doesn't work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put them all together and use `GroupBy` again with both properties:

```
var gruppoRepetitions = Sums.Concat(Sums2).Concat(Sums3)
    .GroupBy(s => new{ s.Gruppo, s.Serie })
    .Select(g => new{ Gruppo = g.Key.Gruppo, Repetition = g.Count() });
```

Comment: I get two errors with this code: s is not defined, the type System.ValueTuple'2' is not defined or imported

Comment: @Gabriele: what C# version are you using? The `s` typo is fixed. If you cant use ValueTuples you can use an anonymous type. I will change it. Done

Comment: ok, now it works! I only deleted the s.Serie in the GroupBy to obtain what I needed. Thank you very much!